# Tunnel URL not found, falled back to LAN URL

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, tunnel

How do I run my expo app using the tunnel? It worked last week but for the last 3 days, it stopped working.

Code written: `expo start --tunnel`

[image: Logs received]

Methods I tried:

1. I used 3 different networks. One using public wifi, one using home wifi and lastly using 4G hotspot.
2. Logging into expo account before running  `expo start --tunnel` https://forums.expo.io/t/tunnel-url-not-found-failed-back-to-lan-url/14380/7

Is there any other way I can try to make the Tunnel URL to work?

EDIT: Sorry for the late update, but the solution I got is in this link!
[Expo forum discussion](https://forums.expo.io/t/tunnel-url-not-found-falled-back-to-lan-url/34623)

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find the solution or workaround for this?

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2459

Answer (score 8):

**Updating these node packages solved my problem:**

`expo-cli and @expo/ngrok`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message, but running the command `r` to restart expo worked for me.

```
expo r --tunnel
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 2):

Your development laptop/computer needs to be on the same network as your mobile.

I connected my phone to my home wifi router and turned off 4g

Then I connected my laptop to the same wifi router

I created an account with expo and logged in by performing **expo login** and filling in the details

I then published by performing **expo publish**

I then scanned the qr code and it loaded and build the project onto my iphone

I then went into the root of the project and typed **expo start --tunnel** and it worked

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to point out that I am logged into my expo account. I also removed `babel-preset-react-native`, and am now using `metro-react-native-babel-preset`, because the former was [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react-native). These might be a few things you want to try if it still doesn't work. Find instructions for Metro [here](https://github.com/facebook/metro/tree/main/packages/metro-react-native-babel-preset).

Anyway, the thing that worked for me was **downgrading to Node LTS**.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are not intuitive, so here is a fix:

1. `npm install @expo/ngrok`
2. `brew install ngrok`
3. `ngrok http 3000`
4. `expo start --tunnel`

Answer (score 0):

## Worked when i connected my device and turned on usb tethering

Even i had the same issue . i pressed ctrl+c and then this time tried this command : "expo restart"
After this, i got a message in terminal saying "tunnel ready"

Answer (score 0):

I solve this. Installing @expo/
ngrok the version who expo was trying to install. After that I run

> **expo start --tunnel**

Again it works but fail again. To solve this I just need to **click in tunnel connection** again in expo dashboard and it works.

When I restart my computer and restart app with **expo start --tunnel** it works well and don't stop again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a silicon chip you might need to install rosetta 2 by entering the following command into a terminal: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was running this command:

`sudo npm install @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I had to install `ngrok` independently, both global and for my project.

```
npm install @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0 
npm install --global @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0
```