# Tunnel URL not found, falled back to LAN URL while running the "expo start --tunnel" command

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to run a react-native application using expo tool.
The expo version I am using is : 3.17.23
Node version: v12.14.1
Watchman version: 4.9.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.8

On running the command: "expo start --tunnel"
I am getting the error:

```
Starting project at /Users/mshikher/Documents/reactNative/GitHub/helloWorld
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.
Your native app is running at exp092374a8475942de845719c6d43d81c5://192.168.0.177:19000
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.
```

I referred this link: [Tunnel URL not found, falled back to LAN URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635880/tunnel-url-not-found-falled-back-to-lan-url)
But it is of no help to me. And I made sure the network I am using in the laptop and the mobile is the same. Still I am getting this error. What is the resolution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed this json object from app.json file
"detach": {
      "iosExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/ios-v2.11.2-sdk33.0.0-76da9dd8-735b-43b3-9682-b386811f4e5f.tar.gz",
      "androidExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/android-v2.11.4-sdk33.0.0-6a4f0f3e-1f1b-4c33-9155-d0237f6d7c34.tar.gz"
    },

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I made sure the proper ngrock is installed and it worked after.

```
npm install @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0
```